# In superset dashboard I can either have filter applied to all charts or none

Tags: filter, dashboard, apache-superset

I added a filter box chart to my dashboard. It works fine as long as the filter is applied to all the charts in the dashboard. When I edit the json to have some charts immuned to filter the filter box stops working altogether. The superset version is 0.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug in 0.28 version of superset. After updating it to 0.29 RC 8 the problem is solved.